# Is it possible to pass the address of array in a function like C++ - PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible to pass an array and start with the second element of the array in order to overwrite with the `$hello` variable?

```
function copyToString($src, &$dst){
    $length = strlen($src);
    for($i =0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $dst[$i] = $src[$i];
    }
}
$arr = ['h','a','m','b','u','r','g','e','r'];
$hello = ['h','e','l','l','o'];
copyToString($hello,$arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice) and pass position what you need as an argument:

```
$arr = ['h','a','m','b','u','r','g','e','r'];
$hello = ['h','e','l','l','o'];
array_splice($arr, 2, count($hello), $hello);
print_r($arr);
// Output:
Array ( [0] => h [1] => a [2] => h [3] => e [4] => l [5] => l [6] => o [7] => e [8] => r )
```